# Angular 2 - Post and Get no working

Tags: angularjs

I'm working locally with Angle 2 I'm breaking my head trying to run, the code works but in the browser inspector post or get methods are never executed.

[image]

leave the links with the code, I am new to this and I could not place the code, sorry!

**Hero-list.component.promise.ts**

s16.postimg.org/b7jo7g2d1/list_component_promise.jpg

**Hero-list.service.promise.ts**

s16.postimg.org/njmkkxq7p/hero_service_promise.jpg

**Hero-list.component.html**

s16.postimg.org/nkwiecs1h/html.jpg

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: You should really get your code on here. Without it nobody will be able to help you. As an alternative to pasting your code in the question, how about using [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/), [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/) or something similar

Comment: Agree on seeing the code. Random thoughts are that if it works locally then it could be CORS and preflight. If it is not then then add a generic exception capturer which should show exceptions the browser is not catching  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3039-logging-error-streams-to-the-server-in-angular-2-beta-6.htm       (this link is prior to the full release so might need adjusting)

Comment: thanks, when I try to paste the code in question does not allow me to confirm, I'll try to write the code.